# "Couldn't get connection factory client"API Key is fine

Tags: android

Ok this has been making me crazy. I get the following crash (Couldn't get connection factory client), but my Maps API key is fine.

This line causes the crash

```
     mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, somePoint);
```

But if I omit the toPixels part it runs fine, but does not do what I want it to do(display an image on a map).

Any guidance? This seems like a different issue than the API key issue and I am testing on a device running Android 2.2, if that it matters.